# Codeigniter bootstrap search result pagination missing

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

I am using CodeIgniter pagination class and everything works fine. Data was found when searching but the pagination link does not comply with the search results. 
For example : search results is one of data but the links page there are two.

this is my code :

```
function view_search($offset=0) {
$jml = $this->db->get('kategori');
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'paging/cari_data';
  $config['total_rows'] = $jml->num_rows();
  $config['per_page'] = 5; 
  $config['uri_segment'] = 3; 
  $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
  $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm' style='position:relative; top:-25px;'>";
  $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
  $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
  $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
  $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
  $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
  $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
  $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
  $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
  $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
  $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
  $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $data['halaman'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
  $data['offset'] = $offset;
  $data['data'] = $this->model_pagination->cari_data($config['per_page'], $offset);
  $this->load->view('view_paging',$data);
 }
```

Model :

```
function cari_data($num,$offset)  {
    $cari = $this->input->POST ('cari');
    $this->db->order_by('id_kategori','DESC');
    $this->db->like('nama_kategori', $cari);
    $query = $this->db->get("kategori",$num, $offset);
    return $query->result();
 }
```

View :

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('paging/view_search');?>">
<input type=text name=cari> <input type=submit value="cari">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
    $config[‘use_page_numbers’] = TRUE;
```

So the pagination uses page numbers. Not offset . 
Comment this line (Default is false) .

```
    //$config[‘use_page_numbers’] = TRUE;
```

then  your view_search($offset = 0)   function will get correct $offset  value.

Comment: I use it to spruce up a uri segment.                                                                  ex : http://localhost/MYWEB/paging/view/3 that url was call when i click link paging number 3.

Comment: @bluesvega ... in the $data['data'] = $this->model_pagination->cari_data($config['per_page'], $offset);  just add ($offset-1)*$config['per_page'] instead of $offset   . Then the correct data set will be populated . If i elaborate more , for the paging number 3 the offset in $this->db->get("kategori",$num, $offset); should be (3-1)*5 = 10 .